# Can I feed a wild Pokemon multiple Razz Berrys to increase my changes of a successful capture?

Tags: pokemon-go

I understand that Razz Berrys increase my chances of a successful capture. I normally only feed a Pokemon 1 Razz Berry, but sometimes they still escape.

[image: Razz Berry]

Will my chances of a capture increase if I feed a Pokemon more than 1 Razz Berry?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You cannot feed them more than one Razz Berry per capture attempt.  I have tried to do it, but, after the first Razz Berry is fed, the Razz Berry item is not selectable on the item screen.

I guess this does reset after another capture attempt, when the pokeball hits but then the pokemon escapes again.  After that happens, you can feed another time, but they still do not stack.  (See comments below.)

Comment: Ah, perhaps I should have tried it before. I guess I just assumed you could feed them multiple xD

Comment: You CAN use multiple berries on a single wild Pokemon, but they won't "stack". If when you first encounter a wild Pokemon, give it berry, attempt to catch it but the Pokemon breaks free, you can feed another berry provided the Pokemon didn't flee. A Pokemon that was fed a berry but breaks free, negates the previous berry.

Comment: @Ekmod, have you done this yourself?  I've tried to feed multiple times, and it didn't work.

Comment: I've done what I've described in my comment. I haven't fed multiple times in a row. But I have fed a Pokemon a berry, attempted and failed to catch it, and then fed it another berry before another attempt. Now that I think about it though, I didn't check if my berry count actually decreased. The selection of the berry was available when going into the backpack after the failed attempt and the animation did play. Also, from my experience, this re-feeding only works when the Pokemon escapes a Pokeball, not when you miss or the ball in knock away by an "attack" of the wild Pokemon.

Comment: I can verify the behavior that @Ekmod describes.

Answer (score 1):

No, Razz Berries do not stack.